# First person about forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I found that forge uses an orthogonal camera by default, but the first person uses a perspective camera. After the first person function is activated and deactivated in the toolbar, it does not switch back to the orthogonal camera. Is this a bug?

Comment: What version of Viewer and what are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @BryanHuang  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=5.0.*

Comment: @BryanHuang Just switch to the first person and then disable the first person and find that there is no switch back to the orthogonal camera.